# What is the appropriate way to handle an async error within a promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

I ran into a bit of a strange situation. I have a function which will send a command over ethernet to a controller and await a response (where `:` means success and `?` means failure). Here is my current code.

```
send(command, timeout=5000) {
  let listener = _.noop;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    listener = Meteor.bindEnvironment(data => {
      data.split(/\r\n/).forEach(line => {
        if (/^\:$/.test(line)) resolve(command);
        // ** this is where the problem is **
        if (/^\?$/.test(line)) reject(command)
      });
    });
    this.on('data', listener).write(`${command}\r\n`);
  }).timeout(timeout).finally(() => {
    this.removeListener('data', listener);
  })
}
```

Now, here is the catch:

If I get an error in my promise, I will have to run another command in order to get the error code ([the TC command from this reference](https://www2.keck.hawaii.edu/inst/deimos/com40x0.pdf)). I want the reject to use the response returned from this command, which is another asynchronous operation that I will have to run within the existing promise.

What is the proper way to do this in asynchronous code?

Comment: Calling `resolve` and `reject` from inside a loop is weird.

Comment: yep, it's more or less just skipping over messages that are not success or failure. For example, if you use `MG "Hello"` it will output `Hello\r\n:\r\n`, and `Hello\r\n` is just kind of skipped over

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do it *inside* the promise. You can just chain a [`.catch`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/catch.html) after the promise:

```
_send(command, timeout) {
  let listener = _.noop;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    listener = Meteor.bindEnvironment(data => {
      data.split("\r\n").forEach(line => {
        if (line == ":") resolve(command);
        if (line == "?") reject(command);
      });
    });
    this.on('data', listener).write(command+"\r\n");
  }).timeout(timeout).finally(() => {
    this.removeListener('data', listener);
  })
}
send(command, timeout=5000) {
  return this._send(command, timeout).catch(err => {
    if (e instanceof Promise.TimeoutError) throw e;
    return this.send("TC1", 500).then(errcode => {
      throw new Error("error code for "+err+": "+errcode);
    }, () => {
      throw new Error("could not fetch error code for "+err);
    });
  });
}
```